# Problems while adding new controller .NET 6 in react template

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net

I created a new .NET 6 with react template (Visual Studio 2022).

I added a new API controller called `ValuesController`:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET: api/<ValuesController>
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

Inside the defalut `FetchData.js` page I changed to:

```
async populateWeatherData() {
    const response = await fetch('api/values');
    console.log(await response.text());
}
```

When I click F12 in the browser the response I get is:

> The development server has disconnected.
> Refresh the page if necessary.
> FetchData.js:56
>
> -->
>   
>   
> Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/favicon.ico" will work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
>
> ### Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
>
> Project1

```
<noscript>
  You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>
<!--
  This HTML file is a template.
  If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

  You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
  The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

  To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
  To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
-->
```

Also I tried to update inside `setupProxy.js`:

```
const context =  [
    "/weatherforecast",
    "/values"
];
```

In other words I don't know why I don't get an answer from my controller.

Comment: Check your network tab in your browser for errors.

Answer (score 0):

1. Inside `setupProxy.js`  add:

```
const context =  [
    "/weatherforecast",
    "/values"
];
```

2. Run `npm run build`

Solved my problem

Comment: I guess - `/api/values`